# data contract break service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a service that has several void/bool methods() and when I refresh the service reference on the client I can see those methods.

The issue is when I add a method with a custom type and supply it with all the correct tags datacontract/datamember, when I update the service reference again on the client nothing gets built not even the existing methods.  No errors are spit out and I'm stuck with no clues on where to turn.

I also tried pulling in the service1 that is created as an example in to my client and it didn't get the composite type either.

The client is MVC4.  The entire stack .net 4.

EDIT
After further review and testing,  the problem is not with the service project or any of the data contracts.  It is with the mvc project generating the reference.cS file.  It is not generating the file or reporting an error on why it's not creating it.  I proved this by opening a brand new empty mvc project and added the service reference and it generated everything perfectly.

Comment: Hi, if you are using custom types then you may need to add a KnownTypes attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and share the generated assemblies across client and server as shown here..
http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/08/wcf-tips-and-tricks-share-types-between-server-and-client.html

Hope this helps,

Comment: Can you post your definition? DataContract and datamember.